# select next element only

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

In my code I have three checkboxes. Out of three, the first one has no class and rest of them have `hidecheck`. Now I want when the checkbox is checked then the div add class `hidecheck` and remove the `hidecheck` from next class' Please help me doing this.

I have applied jQuery code but it only add the class `hidecheck` and removes all the next `hidecheck` class.

I want when click first checkbox it will show the second checkbox only and then when check on second checkbox then it will add `hideclass` and remove from last one

```js
$('.fa-thumbs-o-up').on('click', function() {
  $('.imgtext').addClass('hidechktext');
  $('.imgtext').siblings().next('.imgtext').removeClass('hidechktext');
});
```

```css
.hidechktext {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgtext">
  <a class="nextimgs">
    <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img1" id="chkimg1">
    <label for="chkimg1">
      <p> 
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
        LikeA
     </p> 
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="imgtext hidechktext">
  <a class="nextimgs">
    <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img2" id="chkimg1">
    <label for="chkimg1">
     <p> 
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
        LikeB
      </p> 
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="imgtext hidechktext">
  <a class="nextimgs">
    <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img3" id="chkimg1">
    <label for="chkimg1">
      <p> 
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
        LikeC
      </p> 
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: where is like A? and like B?

Comment: post your html here

Comment: i've added that

Comment: @Tanmay just FYI your HTML was not visible due to the formatting of your question - hence the comments above and the downvotes. I'd suggest you take the time to make sure your question is readable before you post them in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Grab first and last `$('.imgtext')` elements.
- Check to see if you are in last `$('.imgtext')` element, if you are, show back the first `$('.imgtext')`.
- Otherwise hide current on click and show next `$('.imgtext')`.

```js
$('.fa-thumbs-o-up').on('click', function() {
  var LikeC = $('.imgtext').last();
  var LikeA = $('.imgtext').first();
  if (!LikeC.hasClass("hidechktext")) {
    LikeA.removeClass('hidechktext');
  }
  $(this).siblings().parents('.imgtext').next().removeClass('hidechktext');
  $(this).parents('.imgtext').addClass('hidechktext');
});
```

```css
.hidechktext {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgtext">
  <a class="nextimgs">
    <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img1">
    <label for="chkimg1">
      <p> 
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
        LikeA
     </p> 
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="imgtext hidechktext">
  <a class="nextimgs">
    <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img2">
    <label for="chkimg1">
     <p> 
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
        LikeB
      </p> 
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="imgtext hidechktext">
  <a class="nextimgs">
    <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img3">
    <label for="chkimg1">
      <p> 
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
        LikeC
      </p> 
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that is the code I was looking for.But one bug is there you click it and you will see the A tag sometimes comes with an auto tick .Please let  me know the solution

Comment: @Tanmay, edited above, that is caused by the input id (chkimg1), you can either remove them (which I did) or switch them to a class if you wish to repeat them. IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery to just pick the current `.imgtext` div and add class on it and remove from other siblings `.imgtext` div

```
$('.fa-thumbs-o-up').on('click',function(){
    vat currentParentElement=$(this).parents('.imgtext:first');
    currentParentElement.addClass('hidechktext');
    currentParentElement.siblings('.imgtext').removeClass('hidechktext');
    $(this).parents('input:first').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: It works but the first div i.e the checkbox A remains fixedly. How to remove the Option A also after click

Comment: @Tanmay Do you want to uncheck the checkbox, i included that code in my answer

Comment: look check box is in the div .I want when i click on first checkbox it should add the 'hidechktext' so that that selected div should be gone and remove that 'hidechktext' from second div and then when it is checked then it will add 'hidechktext' to third div and remove that class from second one

Comment: @Tanmay hey, the answer is according to your requirement in the question, you got the idea so you should try little bit more